# Should I pack parameters of my rest controller into class or as seperate strings spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a controller with multiple endpoints. Those endpoints serve the same domain. But the input parameters differ a bit from each other.

For example:

```
endpointA:  
 - username  
 - firstname  
 - address   

endpointB:
 - username
 - phoneNumber
 - addresss

endpointC:
 - username
 - email
 - workAddress
```

At the moment every parameter is a String which I pass it to the service responsible for handling the endpoint... 
I am also performing validation. Each parameter has its own requirements for validating. So I implemented a custom validation (just a class with static methods for each param I need to validate) for each of them and validate those string before passing them to the service.

I found a really nice way of doing validation:
http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/
Here he creates a model and on input param it validates it with `@Valid` validation logic is implemented with custom validator and can be specified for every attribute.

I havent found a way to do this for String and doing it for every param. So I thought I would create a wrapper object for each endpoint's params. Annotate attributes with custom validators and that's it. The problem is that with multiple endpoints I'd have lots of classes and duplicate code...

Is it sensible to create a UserRequest object. Implement validation on every attribute and have that object as input parameter on each endpoint.

End result would look like:

```
UserRequestModel
  @usernameValidation
  username
  @firsstnameValidation
  firstname
  @addressValidation
  addresss
  @phonenumberValidation
  phoneNumber
  @emailValidation
  email
  @workaddressValidation
  workaddress

endpointA:  
 - UserRequestModel 

endpointB:
 - UserRequestModel

endpointC:
 - UserRequestModel
```

Attributes not needed in all endpoints would be marked as optional.
I also use swagger for API docs that auto-generates endpoints for testing API. Would be possible to tell swagger which attributes are needed for each endpoint?

I am looking for tips and best patterns to handle situations like this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in having three different classes, one for each of your endpoints, and each of them would define their fields (even if duplicate). You have the validation logic in one place only. For example, the logic for `@usernameValidation` is defined only once, in the validator implementation.

So, I would go for:

```
UserRequestModelA
  @usernameValidation
  username
  @firsstnameValidation
  firstname
  @addressValidation
  address

UserRequestModelB
  @usernameValidation
  username
  @phonenumberValidation
  phoneNumber
  @addressValidation
  address

UserRequestModelC
  @usernameValidation
  username
  @emailValidation
  email
  @workaddressValidation
  workaddress

endpointA:  
 - UserRequestModelA

endpointB:
 - UserRequestModelB

endpointC:
 - UserRequestModelC
```

---

Alternatively, if you'd really want some sort of fields re-usage, you could opt for class extension. You should have a base class that has only the common fields, and your other classes specific per endpoint would extend that base class, as below:

```
UserRequestModel
  @usernameValidation
  username

UserRequestModelA extends UserRequestModel
  @firsstnameValidation
  firstname
  @addressValidation
  address

UserRequestModelB extends UserRequestModel
  @phonenumberValidation
  phoneNumber
  @addressValidation
  address

UserRequestModelC extends UserRequestModel
  @emailValidation
  email
  @workaddressValidation
  workaddress

endpointA:  
 - UserRequestModelA

endpointB:
 - UserRequestModelB

endpointC:
 - UserRequestModelC
```

Comment: Good idea about extending classes. The problem is that I have around 7 endpoints. Some with same attributes some with different attributes. And then 3 diffent controllers. Totally around 16 endpoints. I don't want to complitate things but on the other hand id like to follow best practices / patterns while keeping application maintainable